# Как получить имя компьютера в chrome расширении?

Tags: chrome-extension

Можно ли в расширении chrome получить имя устройства или другую уникальную информацию для этого устройства (можно да уникальный id) на котором работает chrome?
Расширение подключается к серверу и мне нужно как-то идентифицировать какое устройство подключилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучший способ - генерировать идентификатор на сервере при первом обращении и сохранять на клиенте.

Chrome Extension API не предоставляет подобных идентификаторов.
Были прецеденты вроде `experimental.systemInfo.*`, но такие вещи вряд ли когда-нибудь выйдут в продакшн(Читай, будут доступны в расширениях в Store).

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри документацию по API [chrome.identity](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#type-AccountInfo)

Возможно, это то, что тебе нужно